# DependencyPropertyDescriptor help required

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a simple WPF app, where I have a combobox and a label, using dependency property I want to show the selected Item in label, when user select any item in the combobox, label will be changed accordingly.
Here is my code.

```
    public event EventHandler _itemChanged;
    public MainWindow()
    {
        List<String> items = new List<string>();
        items.Add("C");
        items.Add("C++");
        items.Add("C#");
        items.Add("Java");
        items.Add("Js");
        InitializeComponent();
        combx.ItemsSource = items;
        _itemChanged += MainWindow__itemChanged;
        DependencyPropertyDescriptor dpcombx;
        dpcombx =      
              DependencyPropertyDescriptor.FromProperty((DependencyProperty)
              ComboBox.SelectedValueProperty, typeof(ComboBox));

        dpcombx.AddValueChanged(dpcombx, _itemChanged);
    }
    void MainWindow__itemChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ComboBox cb = (ComboBox) sender;

        lbl_Combx.Content = (string)cb.SelectedItem;
    }
```

---

The problem is, EventHandler is not getting called. Please help me.

### here is the XAML

```
<Window x:Class="DP.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <ComboBox Name="combx"
              HorizontalAlignment="Left"
              Margin="57,121,0,0"
              VerticalAlignment="Top"
              Width="120" />
    <Label Content=""
           x:Name="lbl_Combx"
           HorizontalAlignment="Left"
           Margin="368,182,0,0"
           VerticalAlignment="Top" />

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: Why not do it in XAML with single binding? Can you show you XAML?

Comment: ya.. that can be done using XAML binding. But I want to do using dependencyproperty

Comment: did you try using `SelectedItemProperty` instead of `SelectedValueProperty`?

Comment: yes. tried. but no luck, eventhandler not getting called.

Comment: Got Exception :  An exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in WindowsBase.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Unable to cast object of type 'System.ComponentModel.DependencyPropertyDescriptor' to type 'System.Windows.DependencyObject'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass the dependency object (comboBox) in the AddValueChanged instead of its property descriptor.

```
dpcombx.AddValueChanged(combx, _itemChanged);
```